# Concatenating separate commands that download m4a and converts it to mp3 all in one

Tags: command-line, bash, ffmpeg, yt-dlp

I can download the audio using the command below but how can I also convert it into a mp3 file at the same time.

**Example: Download m4a file**

```
yt-dlp -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' <url>
```

**Convert the m4a file to mp3 using:**

```
ffmpeg -i download_audio.m4a -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 22050 -ac 1 -ar 22050 converted_audio.mp3
```

How can I convert these two commands into one? (so I don't have to execute two separate commands)

Comment: The thing you are trying to avoid seems to be the intermediate file. If you cannot use normal pipes (IO redirection) in your commands, you can try _named pipes_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears [`yt-dlp`](https://www.mankier.com/1/yt-dlp) can write to STDOUT with the `-o -` option ... e.g. like so:

```bash
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' URL_HERE
```

And [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe) can read from STDIN/pipe with `-i pipe:` or maybe even `-i -` ... e.g. like so:

```bash
... | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 22050 -ac 1 -ar 22050 converted_audio.mp3
```

So, you can try something like this:

```bash
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' URL_HERE | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 22050 -ac 1 -ar 22050 converted_audio.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8000 -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f mp3 "$(basename "$(yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g')").mp3"
```

To use the same output file name from the pipe as the input name with `ffmpeg`, you can modify the command as follows:

```bash
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8000 -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f mp3 "$(basename "$(yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g')").mp3"
```

Explanation:

1. The `basename` command is used to extract the base name from the URL. It retrieves the video title using `yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4` and then replaces any characters that are not allowed in file names with underscores using `sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g'`.
2. The `$(...)` syntax is used to execute a command and use its output as part of the larger command.
3. `$(basename "$(yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g')").mp3` is the resulting file name with the `.mp3` extension added.